# Kafka streams throwing OutOfMemory exceptions continuously and stops working

Tags: java, apache-kafka, out-of-memory, apache-kafka-streams, spring-kafka

I have set up a streams application which consumes messages from one topic, transforms them and put it to the other topic, if any error happens in serialization it puts the records to the error topic.
The load of messages is huge (in millions). The stream app was working perfectly fine until a few days ao, we loaded around 70M data and it was still doing good, then day before yesterday we added another stream to the same application and started streaming the data, now the application crashes with OOM exceptions. Each of the streams have different topics and consumer groups assigned.
The applications runs for an hour or so and then crashes with "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space" errors.
This application is behaving very strangely, we increased the heap size(Xmx) to 2G on each node, our topology is 2 nodes are running the application which are connected to Kafka broker which is running 3 nodes.
There were no network issues but I frequently see "Attempt to heartbeat failed since group is rebalancing" and consumer rebalancing happening in the logs only for the newly added stream.

kafka clients version - 2.3.1
kafka broker - 2.11

Kafka streams configuration:

````
 ```props.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, kafkaProperties.getBootstrapServers());
        props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass());
        props.put(StreamsConfig.NUM_STREAM_THREADS_CONFIG, 4);
        props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass().getName());
        props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_DESERIALIZATION_EXCEPTION_HANDLER_CLASS_CONFIG, SendAndContinueExceptionHandler.class);
        props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_PRODUCTION_EXCEPTION_HANDLER_CLASS_CONFIG, CustomProductionExceptionHandler.class);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.RETRIES_CONFIG, "1");
        props.put(ProducerConfig.PARTITIONER_CLASS_CONFIG, CustomPartitioner.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
        props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,"org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
        props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
````

````
Streams creation code:



```@Bean
    public Set<KafkaStreams> kStreamJson(StreamsBuilder builder) {
        Serde<JsonNode> jsonSerde = Serdes.serdeFrom(jsonSerializer, jsonDeserializer);
        final KStream<String, JsonNode> infoStream = builder.stream(inputTopic, Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), jsonSerde));

        Properties infoProps = kStreamsConfigs().asProperties();
        infoProps.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, migrationMOIProfilesGroupId);
        infoStream
                .map(IProcessX::process)
                .through(
                        outputTopic,
                        Produced.with(Serdes.String(), new JsonPOJOSerde<>(Message.class)));

        return Sets.newHashSet(
                new KafkaStreams(builder.build(), infoProps)
        );
    }
````

Errors received:

```
[8/6/20, 22:22:54:070 GST] 00000076 SystemOut                                                    O 2020-08-06 22:22:54.070  INFO 83225 --- [s-streams-group] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=streams-group-5c15c2c1-798f-4b4d-91a8-24bd9a093fe6-StreamThread-18-consumer, groupId=streams-group] Discovered group coordinator kafka.broker:9092 (id: 2147483644 rack: null)
[8/6/20, 22:23:22:831 GST] 00000d95 SystemOut                                                    O 2020-08-06 21:27:59.979 ERROR 83225 --- [| producer-3356] o.apache.kafka.common.utils.KafkaThread  : Uncaught exception in thread 'kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-3356':
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

I have checked session.timeout.ms, heartbeat.timeout.ms, max.poll.interval.ms, max.poll.records but Im not sure what values to set for them.

Please help me solve the issue.

Comment: Are you still facing this issue? Perhaps due to the load your nodes are under too much stress caused by garbage collection activities generating too long pauses, which can impact the balance of load. Could you please enable the garbage collector log and attach it?

Comment: Yes, still facing the issue, I will try to get the garbage collector log

Comment: Kafka Streams itself should not use much memory as your app is stateless. You should try to figure out where the memory is actually used -- a JVM heapdump may help.

Comment: I have upgraded the kafka-streams to 2.6 version and the issue is resolved